# Trying to understand billing logic of Firestore for live updates

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

Let's say a user can have many collections of words:
A collection would be a document in Firestore having two properties: name and items.

Now let say I have 2 opened instances of the app, I want to use live update feature so when an item is inserted inside a document from instance A, instance B views will update to show the changes.

The catch is `items` can grow **pretty** huge over time, we are talking about words dictionaries here... So I'm worry that instance B will pull huge amount of data when instance A only add one new item.

How does the cloud accounts for the billing in that scenario? Am I going to be charged for *only* 1 read when instance B live updates or for the amount of data the request contains when instance B live updates?
Maybe it's best not using live update for the latter because words are added one by one in the dictionaries so I would assume the cost can grow pretty huge too.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @MicheleLaFerla read the question and tell me what code I can provide? duh

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the [Firestore documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing?authuser=0&hl=en#listens):

> When you listen to the results of a query, **you are charged for a read
> each time a document in the result set is added or updated**. You are
> also charged for a read when a document is removed from the result set
> because the document has changed.

So, after "Instance A" has received the initial `QuerySnapshot`, if "Instance B" creates or modify a document, it will cost only one read to "Instance A".

Comment: Only one read with no limitation of data transmitted over the network? Even if `items` in the document is ~2MB each time? I guess it's good news.

Comment: Note that in addition to the read cost, "you are charged for the network bandwidth used by your Cloud Firestore requests", see the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing?hl=en&authuser=0#network).

Comment: Also note that a document is limited in size to at most 1MB, so you can't store 2MB of items into a single document.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen That's unfortunate, what would be another solution to store big data bank in the Firebase ecosystem?

Comment: @markus0235 A possible solution would be to split the data across multiple documents.